# MS Excel. VBA function returns #value

Tags: vba, excel

It would be nice if someone could explain what causes function above return #value error.

```
Public Function papild(x)
    Dim Sum As Double, A As Double, pi As Double,
    Sum = 0.5 - (x - pi / 4)
    A = -(x - pi / 4)
    pi = Application.WorksheetFunction.pi()
    Dim k As Integer, i As Integer
    k = 2
    i = 0
    Do While Abs(A) > 0.0001
        A = -A * 4 * A * A / (k + i) * (k + i + 1)
        Sum = Sum + A
        k = k + 1
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    paplid = Sum
End Function
```

Function takes x value from MS Excel cell and it's equal = -1.5708 (=-PI()/2     @Formula Bar)

Comment: `Public Function papild(x)` and `paplid = Sum`, typo alert. Please always use Option Explicit on top of your code for easier problem detection.

Answer (score 5):

In lines 3 and 4 you work with variable pi before setting it in line 5...

Could there be some brackets missing in your formula. It basically says:

```
A = -4A^3 * (k+i+1)/(k+1)
```

This obviously drifts to +/- infinite so your loop cannot end.

Also there is a comma too much in the second line and a spelling error in the last line (paplid instead of papild).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried debugging the code?
When I run the code I get an overflow error @ the 6th iteration of the while loop starting with x = -1.5708. Number gets to large to fit inside variable
.Other than that there are some minor things: 
missing As Double

```
Public Function papild(x) As Double
```

and unnecessary comma at the end

```
Dim Sum As Double, A As Double, pi As Double,
```